# nodejs equivalent of php code involving $_GET and file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, iframe, echo

Can you tell me what is the node.js equivalent of this code:

```
<?php
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $html;
?>
```

The reason I want to be able to do this, is because I want to open an external domain page in an iframe and be able to manipulate the DOM inside the iframe without encounter **same domain policy**.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `node.js`?

Comment: Node.js is server side, not client side.  Why would you think this is possible?

Comment: @CharlesAddis When did he say this is a clientside endeavor? He is simply wanting to create a server-side proxy hosted on the same domain as his web site, and this proxy will read a remote web page. Totally possible in PHP. He just wants to know how to do this in Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@BrandomWamboldt is correct, you simply can't access the other domain's DOM.

As a workaround, you can have your own server download that page and manipulate the DOM. That way you can serve the page from a URL on your domain.

That's not to say it's a good idea, since you're allowing the other site to inject scripts that you pass on to your users. But here's an example of changing another site's page and sending the response from your own domain, using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom):

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
function handler(req, res){
  jsdom.env(
    "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254525/php-echo-equivalent-in-node",
    ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
    function (errors, window) {
      window.$('body').prepend(
        window.$('<h1></h1>').text('Text inserted by Node')
      );
      var doc = window.document;
      var output = doc.doctype.toString()+doc.innerHTML;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(output);
    }
  );
};
require('http').createServer(handler).listen(3000);
```

If you don't care about a DOM on the server side you may be able to simply download the entire remote page with [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) or the [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library, then send the page contents as the response from your domain.

And again this is bad from a security standpoint so you should probably look for alternative solutions

Comment: Hi, Plato. Thank for the info. Just 1 more thing. How can I on the client side put in the iframe the url coming from my domain. eg: <iframe src="http://mydomain.com/externaldomain.com" ></iframe>. I want to be able to browse inside the iframe and at the same time manipulate its DOM. thanks

Comment: That sounds harder than rendering a one-shot page with a modified DOM. I would use something like @vp_arth 's method to pass a URL to your route, download the page, and replace all `a` tags with URLs pointing to your server: `<a href="http://google.com">` > `<a href="http://yourdomain.com/mirrorPage?target=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com">`, then serve the modified page

Answer (score 0):

partial equivalent is

```
function h(req, res){
  var query = require('url').parse(req.url,true).query;
  var data = require('url').parse(query.url);
  require('http').request({
    host: url.host,
    path: url.pathname
 }, function(response){
   response.on('data', function (chunk) {res.write(chunk);});
   response.on('end', function () { res.end(); });
 })
}
require('http').createServer(h).listen(80);
```

res.write here sends data to the browser
sure you can store all it in some variable and put it to your own template

Upd: add using get parameter `url`